# Deleting and moving files is sluggish starting today on Windows 7 with SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I have an SSD on a Windows 7 laptop, and it worked extremely well for past 3-4 month. I followed several guides to minimize writes to it etc.

Today, I noticed that deleting files is very slow. Also while moving (`Ctrl-X`), the original file disappeared after 5-8 seconds. Which is pretty slow!

Is there anything I can do to see what's wrong?

Comment: You might want to tell us what steps you actually took to minimise writes...

Comment: And list your SSD.

Comment: yes, sorry. It's OCZ-VERTEX2 40GB - I followed this steps: DISABLE SYSTEM RESTORE, DISABLE DRIVE INDEXING, DISABLE DRIVE DEFRAGMENTATION, TURN OFF PAGEFILE, TURN OFF HIBERNATION, DISABLE PREFETCH AND SUPERFETCH. That's about it, if I remember correctly :)

Comment: Turning off the page file *might* cause this kind of strange behaviour.

Comment: This common for OCZ (and others?) if the drive is getting full. Clearing some space, more than 10%,  and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, all I can think of is the TRIM function is off.  Unlikely, but might as well check.

`fsutil behavior query disabledeletenotify` should equal to zero.

Deleting a file could be because the recycle bin is full.

Comment: command gave me 0. Recycle bin is most of the time empty.